# how to create a unfixed length slice in golang

Tags: go, slice

Is there any way to create a **unfixed length** slice in go? As a example, I want to grab all the fileNames in a directory(`content/`) fill to  a `[] string` slice.

The `content/` dir contains:

```
$-> tree content/
content/
├── 1.txt
├── 2.txt
└── tmp
```

Here is what I currently got:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func listFile() []string {
    list := make([]string, 100)
    // as you can see, I make a slice length as 100, but that is not appropriate.

    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("content")
    i := 0
    for _, f := range files{
        list[i] = f.Name()
        i = i+1
    }
    return list
}

func main(){
    fmt.Print(listFile())
}
```

What I want to achieve is a way to simulate the behavior of `ArrayList` in java, which I can just simply `list.add()` and wont care about the length.

Can slice in GoLang do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Go slice can't do that, but the `append()` function will grow your slice in a matter that appending elements becomes an *O*(1) amortized operation:

```
func listFile() []string {
    // make a slice of length 0
    list := make([]string, 0)

    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("content")
    for _, f := range files {
        // append grows list as needed
        list = append(list, f.Name())
    }

    return list
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have go all through the [official blog](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals) again and have a better view of GoLang's slice mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

To produce a slice of names from a slice of `FileInfo`, you don't need anything like the Java `ArrayList`.

`ioutil.ReadDir()` returns you a slice of `FileInfo` of which you can query its length using the built-in **`len`** function:

```
count := len(files)
```

So you you can make an array or slice capable of holding names of this amount:

```
func listFile() []string {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir("content")

    list := make([]string, len(files))
    for i, f := range files {
        list[i] = f.Name()
    }

    return list
}
```

Comment: Upvote for providing the right solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an empty slice and append to it with `append`. If you know more or less the average size you're expecting, you can reserve some space for it, just like in Java's ArrayList. This will prevent reallocating the underlying data when the slice grows.

```
//make an empty slice with 20 reserved items to avoid 
list := make([]string, 0, 20)reallocation

// now we just append to it. The underlying data is not copied
list = append(list, "foo") // add to it
```

Comment: Thanks, this reserved suggestion really make a spark for me.